# Laravel - handling a large number of small data entries in a single request with total execution time 2+ minutes

Tags: laravel, asynchronous, import

TLDR: I have a 150 second loop to run triggered by a HTTP request, I need to async this as the request will die due to time before it's completed - Laravel Queues seem to handle a large single import, not thousands of small ones - so anyone know how to do this?

Longer version:

I'm trying to import a large spreadsheet into my MySQL database, but the execution time takes longer than 60 seconds so the request times out. My code loops through the data creating rows in the database:

This is a method within a controller - "ProjectController" the main point is there is a very long loop as there is so much data to process and store

```
public function bulkStore(Request $request)
    {
        $allProjects = $request->all();

        $properties = Property::where('client_id', 1)->get();
        $propertiesArray = [];

        foreach($properties as $property)
        {
            $propertiesArray[$property->name] = $property->id;
        }

        foreach($allProjects as $project)
        {
            $project = json_decode(json_encode($project), true);

            $project_id = Project::create([
                'client_id' => 1,
                'reference' => $project['Reference'],
                'name' => $project['Project Name'],
                'description' => null,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

            ])->id;



            foreach($project as $property => $value)
            {
                if(!in_array($property, array('Reference', 'Project Name')))
                {

                    $property_id = $propertiesArray[$property];

                    $value = json_encode($value);

                    DB::table('property_values')->insert([
                        'project_id' => $project_id,
                        'property_id' => $property_id,
                        'data' => $value,
                        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure where to put this code and how to handle the request so that it's completed in the background after a quick validation 200:ok response is given to the client.

Any help much appreciated - apologies if this loop is hideous - I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: How many records are you sending to controller?

Comment: You can use array_chunk() to insert large number of data

Comment: Why not move this logic to a Job and let the queue worker handle it?

Comment: Number of records are in the region of 10,000+, it's sent as a large array where each item is a spreadsheet line, the sheet has just over 1000 rows and around 30 columns

Comment: It's unlikely to process all at once without reaching max_execution_time; event if you send optimized queries to database that still takes a lot of time. Better dispatch them to a queue job and let Queue consume them. Have a look at Marijan's answer :)

Comment: ok @tamrat I will look into this now :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating eloquent models is the heavy part, I guess. You could just store the given data in a temporary json in file and return a `200 OK`.

```
Storage::disk('your_temp_disk')->put('import.json', json_encode($project));
```

Then queue a job:

```
ImportProjects::dispatch($path_to_the_import_json);
```

Then pick up the file in the `ImportProjects` job, create your models and finally delete the temporary file.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this now then :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the logic to a job.

In your controller

```php
use App\Jobs\ProcessProperties;

public function bulkStore(Request $request)
  {
    $allProjects = $request->all();

    $properties = Property::where('client_id', 1)->get();

    ProcessProperties::dispatch($properties);
  }
```

**`app/Jobs/ProcessProperties.php`**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class ProcessProperties implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

  protected $properties;

  public function __construct($properties)
  {
    $this->properties = $properties;
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    $propertiesArray = [];

    foreach($this->properties as $property)
    {
      $propertiesArray[$property->name] = $property->id;
    }

    foreach($allProjects as $project)
    {
      $project = json_decode(json_encode($project), true);

      $project_id = Project::create([
        'client_id' => 1,
        'reference' => $project['Reference'],
        'name' => $project['Project Name'],
        'description' => null,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
      ])->id;

      foreach($project as $property => $value)
      {
        if(!in_array($property, array('Reference', 'Project Name')))
        {
          $property_id = $propertiesArray[$property];

          $value = json_encode($value);

          DB::table('property_values')->insert([
            'project_id' => $project_id,
            'property_id' => $property_id,
            'data' => $value,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
          ]);
        }
      }
    }

    // You can emit and event here to be notified when the job completes
  }
}
```

Then its all about running the queue worker with `php artisan queue:work`.

Comment: Am I able to dispatch multiple things? The $properties variable will infuture lookup properties using 'client_id' dynamically, so when I create this variable i need access to the request, the data itself is dispatched like so: ProcessBulkProjectsImport::dispatch($allProjects);
But can I do? ProcessBulkProjectsImport::dispatch($allProjects, $properties);
Somehow? Laravel Docs dont say :(

Comment: Or is ProcessBulkProjectsImport::dispatch($request); a valid way?

Comment: You can dispatch multiple jobs. You can even dispatch jobs from with in a job.